# AWS Elastic Inference Error: <method> is being compiled since it was called from <another method>

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm working with a task of deploy Elastic Inference on AWS server.

Our model is Tacotron model with encoder, decoder and postnet as it's children.

When I call `torch.jit.script(model)` (model is Tacotron model), It says that the encoder's forward method (Encoder.forward()) is being compile since it was called `Tacotron.encoder.forward()`.

Here is a part of Error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is2Xr.png)

I guess the problem is when  I call `torch.jit.script(Tacotron)`, since I have declared `encoder=Encoder()` in Tacotron's `init`, It' recursively compile Encoder's modules (include forward() method). And then, the `torch.jit.script` compile the Tacotron's `forward()` method (in which I have called `encoder.forward()` method), It tried to compile the encoder's forward method one again.

When I put `torch.jit.ignore` decorator to Tacotron's forward method, the error was gone but the model is so slow (as running on CPU without Elastic Inference)

I have tried to change the Encoder's forward method name to another (say `inference()`), but had no luck.

Please help. Thank you so much.

I'm using Pytorch-eia 1.3.1 from Amazon AMI.

Comment: The problems were there are some class variables has been declare outside the __ini__ method.

The error message is not relevant much. 

For anyone got this error, move all variables of class to the __init__ method.

Comment: did you manage to fix the error? Was it related to the torch scripting or to Elastic Inference? When you say "The error message is not relevant much", which error message was that?

Comment: @OlivierCruchant I mean, the real problem and the message is not matched. I solved this error by moving all object's variable  (start with self.) declaration into __init__ function.

the message was: "<method> is being compiled since it was called from <another method>"

And the problem is related to TorchScript.